# How to make an MSI that simply wraps an EXE file

Tags: installation, windows-installer

After way too many experiments, I've come to the conclusion that Windows Installer is simply bad technology. But the customers want MSI files.

So, how can I create an MSI file that extracts an EXE file to a temporary directory and runs it with options same or similar as were passed to the EXE file?

Options to an MSI are explained in *[Msiexec (command-line options)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262.aspx)* (low level "run" of an MSI is msiexec option package.msi).

EDIT: mjmarsh's WiX solution looks like it works. I just haven't had a chance to try it yet (crunch time). If it works, I'll be accepting it.

EDIT: it does not work. Missing piece: attended/unattended does not seem to be available.

Anyway, the only to make this work at all would be for the custom action to kill its parent process!

EDIT: So somebody posted as a further answer wrapping the whole thing as a post-install custom action. Theoretically possible but since a reboot may be required (thanks MS for .NET 4 requiring a reboot sometimes) we have to do further hackery. So from the matrix of advantages:

```
Transparency: No. One big custom action.
Customizability: No.
Standardization: No. 
Management and reporting: No. Appears to work but will not.
Security: No benefit.
Validation: No. The hackery required to survive reboot makes this sure to not work.
Resiliency: Completely defeated.
Rollback: No. Rollback didn't work when we were using MSI anyway.
Patching & Updates: No. We have a local solution anyway.
Logging: No. Appears to work but will not.
```

No point.

Comment: So, a lot of people are looking at this. Unfortunately there is no solution, and most of the developers are now in favor of not using MSI period.

Comment: It is entirely possible to run an EXE file during an MSI install, and I have done so several times. It is just a matter of sequencing and verifying that the EXE you run exits cleanly. MSI is generally hard to deal with and often requires specialist attention, but the benefit in terms of corporate deployment is very substantial. MSI does enforce a number of rules that make it hard to do unusual and dangeropus things during installation.

Comment: Glytzhkof: try invoking from inside a MSI a third-party EXE that's going to unpack and invoke several MSIs.

Comment: Please read: **["Advantages of using MSI files"](http://serverfault.com/a/274609/20599)** for a summary of the benefits provided by MSI files for corporate use.

Comment: How many is too many?  Two?  I've been doing MSI for 15 years and I promise that if you knew what I knew you'd change your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to `weir's` answer, change the `custom action attribute` like below:

```
<!--Run Action-->
    <CustomAction Id="RunWrappedExe"
                  Return="asyncNoWait"
                  FileKey="ApplicationFileId"
                  Execute="deferred"
                  ExeCommand=""
                  HideTarget="no"
                  Impersonate="yes"/>
```

Setting `Return=asyncNoWai` does not wait for the `exe` to return. The installer does it's job and closes normally. Meanwhile, the `exe` continous its execution.

-Madhuresh

Comment: If I had this answer back in 2009 I might have used it; however it's years too late and we would gain none of the advantages anyway.

Comment: ha ha.. may be it will be useful for somebody else

Answer (score 16):

Well, there is the free way and the $$$ way. I cannot document everything here, but this should get you started.

On a side note, yes, Windows Installer is a maddening technology. There are many times where I think a task will be straightforward, but it actually becomes complicated. You definitely have to immerse yourself to understand it.

In any case, here goes:

**Free: WiX** ([**here**](http://wix.sourceforge.net/))

This is a free tool to generate MSI files from a set of XML configuration files. I'll leave you to find tutorials online, but here is the crux:

You can compress your EXE into the installer by using the following tag in the WXS file:

```
<Binary Id="MYEXE" src="<path to my exe?"/>
```

Then you can create a custom action which launches your EXE file:

```
<CustomAction Id="EXECA_CALLMYEXE" Return="check" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="MYEXE"
      ExeCommand="my command line"/>
```

Then you insert your custom action into the `InstallExecuteSequence` in the appropriate spot (I almost always run mine somewhere between `InstallInitialize` and `InstallFinalize`)

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="EXECA_CALLMYEXE" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[Not REMOVE]]></Custom>
```

**$$$: Get InstallShield** ([**HERE**](http://www.installshield.com/))

First create a "Basic MSI" project and make sure you say you want *no setup.exe generated*. You set this in the Release settings.

Then you essentially do the same thing as with WiX, but you have a UI for it.

- You can specify your helper EXE file by using the Direct Editor and putting your EXE file in the 'Binary' table
- You can create a custom action to launch that EXE file from the "Custom Actions" Node in the tree on the left
- You can insert the custom action by selecting "Install Sequences" and putting it in the `InstallExecuteSequence` somewhere between `InstallInitialize` and `InstallFinalize` as I said before.

Sorry, I could not be more detailed, but this should be a good start.

Comment: The installshield way is already known not to work. It does not extract to a temp directory but to the target directory, running into the same bug we are trying to avoid in the first place (modify date on target file is often flat out wrong).

Comment: Looks like WiX can do it w/ Custom Action and Binary element. Unfortunately the tutorial is currently busted but the help file in the download binary works.

Comment: Huh, I was unaware of the binary extraction issue with IS.  What version do you use?

Comment: We recently had a customer who reported getting a cryptic, undocumented error when running the installer we created with InstallShield. We re-packaged it as an MSI and it ran OK.

We are abandoning InstallShield after years of frustration, and converting to WiX.

Comment: Changing return to `asyncNoWait` instead of `check` seems to be ok for me. The `msi` just quits & the `exe` starts to execute.

Answer (score 6):

I think the easiest way to create a .MSI file is to use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

[Lesson 1](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson1.php) from the WiX tutorial is all you need to create a simple install.

Comment: That link is forbidden(403) now. Granted it is three years later.

Comment: I think the Lesson one should be http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started. But I don't think it has to do with running a EXE from within MSI.

Answer (score 4):

Joshua, I understand your frustration very well. MSI is quirky to say the least - a completely new way to think of deployment. Still, applied correctly MSI offers the best possible deployment, especially for corporate customers.

What operations does your installer EXE perform? Is it largely file copy, some COM registration and some registry writes, or does it run complex installation logic, setting up databases etc...? The reason I ask is because it probably would be very quick to create a well functioning WIX MSI for you so you can abandon the EXE approach.

It is indeed possible to run an EXE from inside an MSI, but it requires proper sequencing, and it is guaranteed to cause you more blues than a simple MSI. If the app is small, and not doing anything crazy during installation, I would be happy to provide you with a basic WIX conversion.

- **[A summary of deployment tools and their strengths and weaknesses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546941/129130)**
- **[Advantages of using MSI files](https://serverfault.com/a/274609/20599)**

Comment: MSI known bug: will not update executable binary that was touched by something else.

Comment: It is not clear to me why an executable binary should be "touched by something else" after deployment? Binaries should essentially be considered read-only after installation?

Comment: We never did find out what was doing it.

Comment: Joshua: very likely a recompiled binary with the same version set. You can deal with this in several ways. The easiest way is to set [REINSTALLMODE="emus"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx) in the msiexec.exe command line. This will replace files of equal or lower version (as opposed to the normal behavior of replace lower versions). I prefer to set automatic version updates for .NET assemblies though using 1.0.* in the project settings.

Comment: Bad guess. We had auto number turned on.

Answer (score 1):

No solution. We went NSIS as corporate MSI install is going to be broken anyway due to MSI nesting problem (just *try* installing EXE wrapping MSI from inside MSI someday).

Comment: Just for the record, here is **[a summary of deployment tools and their strengths and weaknesses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1546941/129130)**. For other people looking to decide how to do deployment.

Comment: Please also read: **["Advantages of using MSI files"](http://serverfault.com/a/274609/20599)** for a summary of the benefits provided by MSI files for corporate use.

Answer (score 1):

Wix can do it. Here is my sample code for wix 3.5:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
   <Product Id='*' UpgradeCode="11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555" 
        Name='My Setup' Language='1033' Version='1.0.0.0' 
        Manufacturer='Your company'>

    <Package Description='pak' InstallerVersion='200' Compressed='yes' />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='setup.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
        <Directory Id="TempFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="~_tmpdir">
                <Component Id='MyComponent' DiskId='1' Guid=''>
                    <File Id="File0" Name="setup.exe" Source="setup.exe" />
                    <File Id="File1" Name="file1.txt" Source="file1.txt" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id='InstallFeature' Title='Install Feature' Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='MyComponent' />
    </Feature>

    <!-- Run Action -->
    <CustomAction Id="RunWrapExe" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" 
                  FileKey="File0" ExeCommand="setup.exe param here"  
                  HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="RunWrapExe" 
                After="InstallFiles">NOT REMOVE~="ALL"</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

   </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Setup.exe might, depending on circumstances, execute the exe for SQLEXPRESS, which runs multiple MSIs.

Comment: Well, single exe can work, for me that will resove all.    For all install file, we build with **great** [InnoSetup](www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to create a exe, and if customer want MSI, we'll packet exe with Wix. This way, there's only one setup script to maintain.

Comment: @weir: Great script. Set Return as `asyncNoWait` so that there is no blocking ;) See my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manage MSI, but only execute EXE, try [Exe to MSI Converter Free](http://download.cnet.com/Exe-to-Msi-Converter-Free/3000-2216_4-10969236.html). You just put in the path to the EXE and get an MSI.

Comment: Do you know what happens when an EXE that was invoked from a MSI invokes an exe that will invoke an MSI (such as .NET 4)?

Comment: No. I don't got this problem. My setup.exe was developed in Inno Setup works, but I don't call any msi from inside exe.

Comment: Then you won't have the problem. Take a working MSI (any MSI), wrap it in an EXE wrapper, then try using this tool to wrap that EXE in a MSI and watch the spectacular result.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [free version of the MSI Wrapper](http://www.exemsi.com/getting-started). It also supports uninstall and upgrades. Also, it only creates one entry in the Add or Remove programs.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

In MSI package, there is a behaviour call "Launch an application after installation", that means your exe file will be executed after the MSI installation(the MSI is closed).

Try to execute your exe there, so when your exe invoke other MSI packages, it won't conflict with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (wrap EXE, call other MSI from the EXE including .net setup, etc.), 
and here is my solution:

I build the setup exe using InstallAware.
It has its own MSI Wrapper that wraps the generated EXE with MSI.

It works OK, the EXE can call other MSIs without any problem (including .net setup, other 3rd party setups), but that is because the launching MSI ends ("returns") rights after it launches the setup EXE file, and that way they avoid the MSI limitation of recursive MSI calls.

BUT - some customers (companies) that uses MSI deployment tools, requires the MSI (msiexec) to return (end) only after the setup process ends, and that is a problem with the above solution.

So - to solve this:

There is another MSI Wrapper (exemsi.com) that generates MSI that returns only after the EXE setup ends, but for using that you must use another unique option of InstallAware:

InstallAware has the option to generate the EXE setup using their own native engine, and not based on Windows Installer engine, to avoid MSI recursive limitation.
Combine those both, and you have the perfect solution.

Hope this will help someone, although many years passed since this question was first posted.

Comment: Apparently you haven't tried it with the custom .EXE running .NET setup.

Answer (score -2):

Simple trick:

[Project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my6E8.png)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Setup
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0);
            Stream st = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Setup.MSI.Temp.msi");
            string path = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "Temp.msi");
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                st.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the question again.

Answer (score -4):

Nah man, just use Inno Setup's wizard. It makes an setup EXE but not an MSI. It's like 5 mins and you'll have a windows installer.

Simply [download](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php#stable) it, install it, point it to your EXE, and follow the on-screen prompts

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link was self-explanatory, but I added the steps

Comment: This doesnt answer the question, because InnoSetup doesnt support the creation of MSI. The question is how to wrap an InnoSetup exe in an MSI....

Comment: Oh my gosh. NO it's NOT a link to a guide. It's a link to the DOWNLOAD of a program that solves it. If the link dies, then the program isn't available, so the solution doesn't even apply anymore. You're thinking that I"m linking to INSTRUCTIONS