# How to detect an installed Python 3.x (any 3.x) on Windows from an MSI?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, wix

I am authoring an MSI using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) and I would like to detect the presence of any of the Python 3.x versions for my respective packages (I am offering both 32-bit and 64-bit packages).

I searched quite a bit, but other than starting the Python interpreter and then using some of the values tied to `sys` (after importing that), I haven't found any information. Obviously starting the interpreter already depends on the system being configured to have the path to the Python interpreter in `PATH`, which can't be assumed to be given in all circumstances.

Is there a list of the [product](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370854.aspx) /[upgrade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372375.aspx) codes for the individual released versions of Python 3.x to which I can resort in order to detect the presence of Python 3.x using [`AppSearch`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/appsearch.html)?

If not, I'll have to download all Python MSI databases and extract the necessary information. [It's not a big deal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28971679), but I'd prefer authoritative information on this; and since I was unable to find it, I am asking here.

I prefer the list of product/upgrade codes to the usual looking at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` routine. For MSIs the key will anyway [be the product code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105.aspx) of what I'm trying detect.

Comment: // , The "full proof" method here might be useful, if you're desperate: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-tell-if-Python-is-already-installed-on-my-Windows-7-computer