# Replacing old installer with new one

Tags: wix, installshield

I am trying to create a new installer (using Wix) which will going to substitute the current one (InstallShield). Problem is many clients already have the application installed using the current installer. I need my new Wix installer to detect currently installed application perform the update or force the user to uninstall current application before running the new Wix installer.

I am new with creating installers. I need to know which GUIDs (and version numbers) must be the same for the system to know this is actually the same application just a new version. I didn't create the old InstallSheeld installer but I do have access to its code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251034/find-guid-from-msi-file/11261427#11261427

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall the old InstallShield package, you should find out your old upgrade code and use that within your new WiX installer and do a major upgrade (which will ensure that the old package is uninstalled and removed). Check this [Wix Upgrade document](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html) for doing the major upgrade.

Since we are on the topic, you can also make use of the [Dark.exe](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/10196/) to convert the current MSI into WiX source files.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Sorry for not responding, I wasn´t in the office for a few days so I just tested it and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!