# How to get full setup project support in Visual Stuidio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment

Can i use any installation software in visual studio 2012 to create setup projects?

Because many options in setup projects with install-shield limited edition is disabled. I  cannot customize those?

- what can i do to get full customization support in VS 2012?
- can i use any other installation software,then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following posts do address your setup project support issues:

- [Where is Visual studio 2012 Setup project template?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/msbuild/thread/3570f0b3-53c1-4d2e-94fe-16ed7af70bbf)
- [Create MSI or setup Project with visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12378125/1437962)

However, if you are looking for a previous "basic setup and deployment project type Visual Studio Installer" - then they are [**NOT supported anymore**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-)  :(.

Comment: I want o create windows installer projects,but,not interested in "basic setup and deployment project type Visual Studio Installer"tell me-

how can i integrate another installation tool,in visual studio 2012?