# Replace the Installation Folder dialog in Visual Studio Setup Project with my own Installation Folder dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment

As you know, when creating a **Visual Studio Setup project** (with a msi file as output). In the **User Interface** window, there is a dialog named "**Installation Folder**". I want to decorate this dialog (such as use an Office 2007-styled form instead)... I think I have to delete that ugly default dialog from **User Interfaces** and show my own dialog in the custom **Installer** class. However **I don't know how to pass the path which user selects to the default installer.** I mean I don't want to customize and do everything myself (it's not easy and also not necessary) but I just want to use my skinny dialog and this dialog should know **how to pass the selected installation path to the 'next stage'** of the installation process.

I hope you understand my problem and help me out. In fact, if we know how to do the same things when working on Visual Setup projects, we can customize them much more to build diverse setup projects.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do we only really need read the bold?

Comment: Yes, the text in bold are all I want. Thanks. That style will save your time. =))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is **don't** visual studio setup project is simply not meant for this.
also it is **disconinued**:
see:
[Create MSI or setup project with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378125/create-msi-or-setup-project-with-visual-studio-2012)

I suggest to move to [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) or InstallShield.

Comment: I can feel that Visual Studio Setup project is dying, isn't it? It supports less with its Installer class, if you don't need custom GUI, Setup project and Installer class are enough, otherwise it's really hard to customize. (I don't need only a rich GUI but also a Unicode GUI), thanks for your suggestions. But please wait... I still hope there is some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File system editor (select the installer project in the solution explorer, you will see extra options in the solution explorer panel from that click File system editor). Select 'Application folder' press F4 or right click and select properties. There edit the default location.