# Can't find Setup and Deployment in Visual studio 2012 express edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I want to create a setup project in visual studio 2012 express edition but i can't find Setup and Deployment option in other project option.
See my screenshot. So what is the solution for this problem?

[image: Visual studio 2012 express edition screen shot]

Comment: You're a bit stuck with 2012, as support for deployment projects was removed in that version, and the [VS extension which re-enables them](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects) supports VS 2013 and later. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378125/create-msi-or-setup-project-with-visual-studio-2012) for some options.

Comment: Just use VS 2013 or 2015 Community edition (which is free) and add the installer extension.

Answer (score 0):

run visual studio setup and  at inistalling check the clickonce is inistalled. this option is in setup and you need inistal this futher.