# Error 1001 : While Installing Windows Application which has windows service with Install shield Installer

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, installshield

I am currently working with Install shield installer to create a setup for a Windows Application Service based project in .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7-32bit. I have created an installer project without any build errors that does the installation for me. When I install the setup, it is giving me an error 1001 only.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPiN.png)

Comment: what's the configuration of your project. Is it debug any cpu? and Is your  InstallUtilLib.dll is also a 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Which version of InstallShield are you using? There's a known problem with Installer Classes when .NET 4.6 is on the build machine. This particular problem was resolved in ISLE 2015 and IS 2015 SP1.

Comment: You are using Installer classes to ibstall your service. This is unnecessary - if you have a version of InstallShield that supports native install of services using MSIs ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables then use them instead. That error message is just the undocumented error when there is a failure in the InstallUtilLib mechanism that locates and runs your installer class methods.

Comment: Amit dayama, i am working on VS2013 with 32 bit configuration.

Comment: @PhilDW I am not using installer classes

Comment: You need to verify that because I can actually SEE a Project Installer,cs file in your screenshot!!  For starters, every web search you do for error 1001 will say it's related to installer classes, installutillib.dll and so on. Examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026273/error-1001-on-uninstall  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/03/14/msi-installation-fails-while-installing-a-custom-action-with-error-1001-exception-occurred-while-initializing-the-installation.aspx because 1001 is the generic installer managed code custom action error.