# pack dll-files and c-exefile to one file

Tags: c, gtk

I have developed a gtk-app in c-language. Its dependent of certain dll-files. Is there an easy way to pack everything to just one executable file so it becomes portable to other window-computers?

I have searched internet a lot but cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are dancing around the fact that you want to create an installation program that puts your libraries and your program onto other machines.  In addition you might want to be nice and create a nice little icon on the desktop for users to click.  Stack overflow is littered with questions about installers.  You can find one example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941).

Comment: I have to down vote this. Suggesting the status quo is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I really want an answer to do this also. Adding a bunch of dll's to the windows environment can cause problems if dll's have the same name but different versions. Do the dll's for GTk2 work with the dll's shipped with GTK3?. Maybe, but...

Having the entire program in one big exe is the answer. The program becomes portable, runs in several versions of Windows, a lot of good things.

Comment: Installation programs can check files for date and DLLs by version and replace them.  You are right that blindly replacing DLLs is a mistake.