# c# visual studio installer setup project output as one .exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

How can the setup files and prerequisite files from a vs2019 setup project be distributed as one .exe?

```
setup.exe
Setup1.msi
DotNetFX40Client/dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe
```

I know I could just zip/archive, but I was hoping to have a simple Installer.exe, which would include the above. I'm aware of basic binders which would merge them as one, but

```
setup.exe
```

needs to be the initial executed file, and then setup1.msi & dotnetfx40 are just references for setup.exe.

Mostly looking for recommendations, as I'm aware some routes raise false flags on avs & that's something I wish to avoid.

Comment: I have [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) on the topic. Very ad-hoc, but maybe give it a skim. There are lots of further links in there. [About MSI & relevant tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130) and [about leading deployment tools (long)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546941/129130). And finally [WiX quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130). Lots of cross-linking in there - might be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/).  It should do exactly what you are asking for.

If this is a commercial application and you want to use what many of the pros use, try [wix](https://wixtoolset.org/) it's free but has a learning curve.