# Create installer for .net core asp.net application and configure appsetings.json in setup

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, windows-installer

i have .net core asp.net application.
I can deploy it using copy pasting files in some folder and configuring iis and installing .net core iis bundle .
Is there any way to automate these things by creating installer and to add edit appsetings.json file during installation only?

Comment: What do you mean copy pasting files in some folder and configuring iis and installing .net core iis bundle? As far as I know, auto deploy application to IIS can be achieved by using web deploy and visual studio. VS supports one-click publish. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis#publish-to-iis) to use web deploy.

Comment: @BruceZhang yes but i want to run it as desktop app , so it will have an installer which will install the bundle do all the stuff and run app inside a custom browser or any browser , its more like a distributed app so deploying it on every client is hectic so just need to create an installer

Comment: Take a look at the commercial frameworks that can help you. You will find predefined support at tools as InstallShield, Advanced Installer or others. Usually this kind of frameworks come with predefined support, but you would have to purchase their license.

Otherwise, you can give it a try to Wix, which is free but you'll have to do everything by yourself.

Check the following discussion: What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer